# Can't update in a Mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am new to back-end web development. I have created a schema for collection. But I can't access it. Below is my index.js

```js
const express =require( 'express');
const mongoose =require('mongoose');
const dotenv =require( "dotenv");
const UserRoute=require("./routes/user");
const app=express();
dotenv.config();
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,{useNewUrlParser: true},()=>{
    console.log("Database connected successfully!!")
});
app.use("/register",UserRoute);

app.listen(8000,()=> console.log("Server connected!!!"));
```

This is my User.js

```js
const mongoose =require('mongoose');
const UserSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
   name:{
    type: String,
    
   },
   age:{
    type:Number,
   }
});
module.exports=mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
```

This is my .routes/user.js

```js
const User=require("../model/User");
const router= require( "express").Router();

router.post("/",async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const newUser=new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            age:req.body.age
        });
        const user=newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json("Account activated");
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
    
});
module.exports =router;
```

And when I am trying to post anything its showing error like this..[PostmanAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3lN0.png)

Comment: Can you validate `reg.body.name` and `reg.body.age` have values in it? You might need to add the [body-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) middleware to your express setup

Comment: I am not sure it may solve the issue but you can try `app.use(express.json())`. It will parse incoming req.body object.

Comment: you're trying to send string value into number field as I saw in postman request. this is not related to your question but I want to tell, you should use await with the save function. newUser.save(); -> await newUser.save();